# The sign of a focal length

Tags: optics, conventions, lenses

We know that for converging lens, $f>0$ , for diverging lens, $f<0$. But for many materials I have read so far, it says that: 
"the focal length of a concave lens is 8 cm."

I thought that the focal length in this case must be negative. Or when it comes to focal length, we need to find the absolute value of $f$?

Comment: More on [sign conventions in optics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+sign*+convention*+optics).

Comment: Thank for your reference. I know that for concave lens f<0 . But how about the focal length. Should we take the focal length as the magnitude of f so that the focal length is positive for all lens?

Comment: I think the magnitude has been quoted.   The negative sign is implied.  Also, there might be other sign conventions, so leaving off the sign avoids conflicts related to different sign conventions.